# Mocking digest authentication in RestEasy

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, resteasy, digest-authentication

I am using RestEasy to develop a REST server and using the mock dispatcher (`org.jboss.resteasy.mockMockDispatcherFactory`) for testing the service in my unit tests. My service requires digest authentication and I would to make that part of my testing.

Each of my services accepts a `@Context SecurityContext securityContext` parameter.

Is there any way is inject a fake `SecurityContext` in the dispatcher so that I can test that my security methods function properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the `SecurityContext` into the context data map in `ResteasyProviderFactory`.

```
public class SecurityContextTest  {

    @Path("/")
    public static class Service {
        @Context
        SecurityContext context;

        @GET
        public String get(){
            return context.getAuthenticationScheme();
        }
    }

    public static class FakeSecurityContext extends ServletSecurityContext {

        public FakeSecurityContext() {
            super(null);
        }

        @Override
        public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
            return "unit-test-scheme";
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void securityContextTest() throws Exception {
        Dispatcher dispatcher = MockDispatcherFactory.createDispatcher();
        dispatcher.getRegistry().addSingletonResource(new Service());
        ResteasyProviderFactory.getContextDataMap().put(SecurityContext.class, new FakeSecurityContext());

        MockHttpRequest request = MockHttpRequest.get("/");
        MockHttpResponse response = new MockHttpResponse();

        dispatcher.invoke(request, response);

        assertEquals("unit-test-scheme", response.getContentAsString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those coming across this issue today, adding Contexts has been moved from the `RestEasyProviderFactory` class into the `Dispatcher` class using `getDefaultContextObjects()` method.

I've edited the old answer with the new call:

```
public class SecurityContextTest  {

    @Path("/")
    public static class Service {
        @Context
        SecurityContext context;

        @GET
        public String get(){
            return context.getAuthenticationScheme();
        }
    }

    public static class FakeSecurityContext extends ServletSecurityContext {

        public FakeSecurityContext() {
            super(null);
        }

        @Override
        public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
            return "unit-test-scheme";
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void securityContextTest() throws Exception {
        Dispatcher dispatcher = MockDispatcherFactory.createDispatcher();
        dispatcher.getRegistry().addSingletonResource(new Service());
        dispatcher.getDefaultContextObjects().put(SecurityContext.class, new FakeSecurityContext());

        MockHttpRequest request = MockHttpRequest.get("/");
        MockHttpResponse response = new MockHttpResponse();

        dispatcher.invoke(request, response);

        assertEquals("unit-test-scheme", response.getContentAsString());
    }
}
```